# Java - read WAV file as a float array

Tags: java, audio, wav

I'm trying to read a [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) file (and in the future also [MP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) and [Ogg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg)) file as an array of floats in Java, much like [libsndfile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libsndfile) in C.

I'm looking at the various documentation in the javax.sampled packages, but I can't find a clear explanation on how to do that; I'd like to avoid recurring to external libraries if possible.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why float array? Wave files are byte stream of audio data.

Comment: I have to extract music-related features from them, so I need float or doubles

Comment: Do you mean extracting RIFF chunks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this page:

http://www.jsresources.org/faq_audio.html

see in particular 9.4: *How can I reconstruct sample values from a byte array?*

It works as expected, by comparing java's output with c++ (libsndfile) and matlab (wavread).
I'm going to put the code on m github account when I have time

Answer (score 2):

JavaSound will only give you "raw" access to the sound data embedded in the WAV file, e.g. 8 bit unsigned PCM or 16 bit signed PCM data (if your WAV files are PCM encoded). In either case, the value of each sample is in the range 0 to 255 or -32768 to 32767 and you simply have to shift the range to fit in -1f to 1f.

You should start with `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(...)` using an appropriate source (File, InputStream or URL), examine the format to check the sample size and the number of channels and then you can read and convert the PCM encoded data from the AudioInputStream accordingly.

Comment: thanks, that is a good starting point. However, how do I scale them? I used the ByteBuffer class to read the integer values, however scaling does not work as expected: the negative values are scaled incorrectly, probably because of integer arithmetic stuff ...

For example, normalizing on the first value, octave gives me 
   1.00000   1.06250  -0.12500   2.31250   0.75000   0.37500  -0.37500   0.50000   0.00000   0.87500

while java gives me
1.0 1.0625 -0.062744140625 2.3125 0.75 0.375 -0.312744140625 0.5 0.0 0.875